# Transcluded input ng-model does not update scope variable passed to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a directive that is essentially a complicated label tag that transcludes an input element and takes the input box's ng-model as a parameter.

```
<div switch model="testObject.switch">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.testObject.switch">
</div>
```

Prior to upgrading to angular 1.4, clicking on the directive updated the ng-model and triggered the watch inside the directive.

Now, clicking on the directive still affects the input box, but the value inside the directive is unaffected.

I would appreciate any insight into what caused this change and how to fix it.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62911kx5/1/)

Comment: For the future, is it not acceptable to put the framework in the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle with working code. If you require ngModel in your directive and watch its $modelValue, you are able to get the behavior that you are looking for.

HTML:

```
<div switch ng-model="testObject.switch">
```

Directive:

```
 booleanSwitchModule.directive('switch', [function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    require: "?^ngModel",
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
        var timesChanged = 0;           

        scope.$watch(function() {return ngModel.$modelValue; }, function (val) {

            if (val != undefined) {
                alert("model changed " + ++timesChanged + " times");

                scope.switchPosition = scope.model;
            }
        });


    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<label class="switch">' +
        'directive scope model: {{ngModel}}' +
        '<span ng-transclude></span>' +
        '</label>',
  }
}]);
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/62911kx5/3/